# Xcode to highlight operators in different color?

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to make xcode highlight operators(".","<>", "()", ";", etc) differently, like it is possible in Visual Studio? It really improves the readability of the code.

There's no such option in the preferences but maybe there's some way to edit coloring file directly and make these symbols appear as reserved words? It's ok if the color is blue, like it is for reserved words - as long as it's not the same color as the generic text. I tried googling a plug-in with this functionality, but couldn't find it. It doesn't seem like there are many xcode plug-ins out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DeoolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Built-in languages.pblangspec* by adding your operators as keywords.

Comment: Thanks, this does look like a good solution. Sadly though, it doesn't work - even adding complete random words wouldn't do much - they just wouldn't turn blue.
I guess I'll keep investigating.